# dc.js: Area selection automatically selects whole chart range of all charts it brushes on

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

In my example I have 1 Chart for range selection and 3 charts which should show the selected area. The problem is after I select a range on the range chart the selection tool gets activated on the other 3 charts and it selects the whole chart range.

`chart.brushOn(ture)`
must be true on all charts because I want to take selections on the 3 other data charts.

Before the range selection:
[image]

After the range selection:
[image]

The chart on the top is only for zooming into the other 3 charts on the bottom with the range slider. But after I zoom into the range I want to select data out of the shown "data frame".

The normal workflow of the user would be:

1. Zoom into the data range you want to see with the 1st chart.
2. Select the data you want in one of the three charts at the bottom

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224229/discussion-on-question-by-felix-waigner-dc-js-area-selection-automatically-sele).

Comment: The moderators moved our conversation to chat, see link above.

Comment: Okay, i wrote you over there.